# VB.NET serializing array variables

Tags: xml, arrays, vb.net, string, serialization

I'm building a Windows Forms Application on vb.net and I'd like to make use of "save" and "open" options for the end user.
What I want to achieve is serialization (binary or XML) upon Save As click event of the current values of some specific variables (mainly arrays), which are declared inside the Form Class, and then deserialization of them upon Open click event.

These events occur inside the Form Class.

This is how my code looks like (trying to serialize "testvar" string array)

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports System.Globalization        

<Serializable()> Public Class app

    Dim testvar(100,100) as string

    ...
    ...(methods)
    ...

    Private Sub SaveToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveToolStripMenuItem.Click


        Dim ser As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(String()))
        Using fs As New IO.StreamWriter("E:\test.xml")
            ser.Serialize(fs, testvar)                 '->ERROR "InvalidOperationException was unhandled
        End Using

    End Sub

End Class
```

What am I doing wrong?
Excuse my ignorance, I am new to serialization.
I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: You have a serializer for `String()` but you want to serialize a `String(,)`. If you're uncertain, just provide `testvar.GetType()`.

Comment: @Nico Schertler I tried that too, but now VS throws "Serialization of  System.String[,] objects is not supported"

Comment: The you need to linearize the array. Just put the rows after each other in a simple array. You need to store the dimensions, too in order to reconstruct the array. It is probably a good idea to create a converter structure or class for that. You might be able to use [Surrogates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.surrogateselector.aspx)

Comment: @Nico Schertler your replies are much appreciated! I will try out your recommendation